# How to open System port(WIn, Linux, Mac) from remote Location?

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, port

I am in middle of R & D that I need to **open any port from the Remote Location**;

My Requirements and Collected Information are as Below:

I used the Tool(s)[***nmap***, etc] to check(get the List) Which are the Ports are open on remote Computer!
I am having a trouble to open a closed port from my system to remote system.
I can open a Port if any of the remote System port is open.

**But What I need to do If All Ports Are Closed?** The Remote system is connected in **LAN(and has Internet)**. **SSH** is not installed on remote System...

Comment: A port is open if a program on the remote side opened it to listen for connections. If there is nothing on the remote side no port will be open. In addition you need to allow the connection by "not blocking" the port with a firewall (but this too cannot obviously be controlled from the outside).

Comment: Thanx, Then I need to make one script that should open desire port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Possible from Outside of remote PC